# Nginx: Wildcard server_name

Tags: regex, ssl, nginx, lets-encrypt, nginx-config

I'm having trouble trouble ignoring ***www*** in my urls.

I have a wildcard SSL certificate for *.example.com
My server should respond to https://randomSubDomain.example.com only
and ignore https://www.randomSubDomain.example.com.

My SSL certificate is only valid for https://randomSubDomain.example.com
not https://www.randomSubDomain.example.com

Here's my nginx server file

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name *.example.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name *.example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    root /var/www/example;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: what about `server_name random.example.com;`

Comment: If you have only a single server definition it will use this even if the server_name does not match. Thus you need to have another definition for a `default_server` with a clear behavior for things it should "ignore".

Comment: @shahaf that wont work for me. I need the SSL certificate to work for multiple domains(multi-tenancy)

Comment: try to use a `www.example.com` server block to block/redirect all request, and use another server with *.example.com` to catch anything else

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Please elaborate

Comment: @MrPickle: I don't know what exactly you don't understand from my comment so I cannot elaborate further. Based on your question you have a single server configuration so this will be used for any kind of requests, no matter if they match the given `server_name` or not. Because there is no different behavior defined in your configuration.

Comment: Your server cannot ignore `https://www.randomSubDomain.example.com` if you point your DNS at it. If the certificate is invalid the browser will complain. The connection to Nginx is established **before** the certificate is exchanged.

Comment: @RichardSmith thank you for your contribution, I've decided to enforce HSTS so that clients aren't allowed to proceed past the error notice.